# Regex to capture escaped strings

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a regex that captures escaped string groups. For example in the following string...

```
\ll\lln-(l*4n)*
```

the only escaped group would be `ll`, but in this string...

```
\ll\lln-\(l*4n)*4\
```

the escape groups would be... `ll` and `(l*4n)*4`.

What would be the best regex to do this, as you can see i need to support all letters, numbers and symbols with the excaption of `\` for obvious reasons?.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use regular expressions, than

```
@"\\([^\\]*)\\"
```

is about as close as you'll get.

[Here is an example of your regex in action](http://rubular.com/r/KDEEwTIToq)

Answer (score 1):

So you want the text between `\` and the next `\`? How about:

```
\\(.*?)\\
```

Edit: Thanks to Sam I Am for that handy regex tool:

http://rubular.com/r/An1hK9DdL2